# set supportedRuntime to .net 2.0 in VS 2010 projects

Tags: .net, vb.net, app-config, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to set supportedRuntime for my vb.net project which i created using VS 2010.
Then i tried setting supportedRuntime  for a sample application containing only form. In .config i have specified as shown below

```
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
</startup>
```

When I try to open exe it does not open. If i specify .net 4 first and then .net 2 in config then it works.

If project is created in VS 2008 then above supportedRuntime  option works properly.

So what is the error actually? Can't i set supportedRuntime to 2.0 in config file?

Comment: Don't include v2.0.50727 if your app actually needs v4.0 to be able to run.  Which it does with default project settings in VS2010.  IIRC, Express requires you to edit the project file by hand if you want to target an older version.  Just don't.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok. Thats correct. If project is able to run in .net 2(does not require .net 4) then? Also i wanted to know why the supportedRuntime  i mentioned didnt work.